# html table -- set column to take remaining space, and at least 300px width

Tags: html, css, html-table

How can I make a column in the middle of an html table, and make it fill the remaining space, while also having a minimum width of 300px?

[Here's a JSfiddle showing what I'm trying to do.](http://jsfiddle.net/skeets23/8ndyfLzj/9/)

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="fixed-width">A set width column</td>
    <td class="remaining-width-or-300-pixels">
    A column with long content, to take the remaining space, and at least 300 pixels. It's OK if it has to trucate.
    </td>
    <td class="fixed-width">A set width column</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
}

table td {
  overflow: hidden;
}

td.fixed-width {
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
}

td.remaining-width-or-300-pixels {
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 300px;
}
```

As you can see, when you adjust the width of the panel, the `min-width: 300px;` is being completely ignored.

Any css (**not javascript**) work-around I can employ to get this working?

> Edit: also, any solution that uses `div` elements instead of `table`, `tr`, and `td` elements won't work, I'm using a library that requires the use of the `table` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem lies with **table-layout: fixed;**

According to [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp), the value fixed will set a fixed table layout algorithm. The table and column widths are set by the widths of table and col or by the width of the first row of cells. Could be why the min-width is not working for the td.

```css
table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  /* table-layout: fixed; */
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
}

table td {
  overflow: hidden;
}

td.fixed-width {
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
}

td.remaining-width-or-300-pixels {
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 300px;
 
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="fixed-width">A set width column</td>
    <td class="remaining-width-or-300-pixels">
    A column 
    </td>
    <td class="fixed-width">A set width column</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is close... but the cells with the `fixed-width` class should have a "fixed width" -- not a min width. They should always be 200 pixels. Also, it doesn't seem like a `max-width` on the `remaining-width-or-300-pixels` is needed, (and, it defeats the purpose, since I want to fill the remaining space *regardless of how much there is.*) In other words, here's this solution, working: http://jsfiddle.net/skeets23/8ndyfLzj/21/

Comment: Yes, that's true. I misunderstood and thought there was a need to truncated the text. Hence added the max-width.

I've also updated the answer. Cheers.

Comment: the `fixed-width` td's need a `min-width: 200px` in addition to the `width: 200px`, or else they can get smaller than 200px wide. Otherwise, this is the ideal solution if you don't want to set a min width for the entire `table` element. So I'll mark your answer as correct. :D

Answer (score 0):

Use `text-overflow:ellipsis` to truncate the text.

```
table {
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
      table-layout: fixed;
      white-space: nowrap;
      color: white;
    }

table td {
  overflow: hidden;
}

td.fixed-width {
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
}

td.remaining-width-or-300-pixels {
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 300px;
}

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="fixed-width">A set width column</td>
    <td class="remaining-width-or-300-pixels">
    A column with long content, to take the remaining space, and at least 300 pixels. It's OK if it has to trucate.
    </td>
    <td class="fixed-width">A set width column</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If I set the width to 300 pixels, all the columns expand to fill the space, instead of just the one. That doesn't accomplish the task here: "fill the remaining space, while also having a minimum width of 300px" The "fixed width" columns should never be larger than their intended 200 pixels.

Comment: Just try to do not use min-width insted of width.

Answer (score 0):

Found a working solution. You have to add the width of the fixed width columns, and then add the min-width for the column that takes the remaining space, and set the min-width of the table to this number.

[Working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skeets23/8ndyfLzj/14/)

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="fixed-width">A set width column</td>
    <td class="remaining-width-or-300-pixels">
    A column with long content, to take the remaining space, and at least 300 pixels. It's OK if it has to trucate.
    </td>
    <td class="fixed-width">A set width column</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
  min-width: 700px;
}

table td {
  overflow: hidden;
}

td.fixed-width {
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
}

td.remaining-width-or-300-pixels {
  background: red;
}
```